# creating Pointer to class inside its member function to achieve polymorphism

Tags: polymorphism

Have a look at the below piece of code.

```
//Base Cls declaration:

class CmdParser_c
{
    public:

    CmdParser_c(){}  
    virtual ~CmdParser_c(){} 

    BOOLEAN ParseInputCmd(UINT8*);
    virtual BOOLEAN ProcessInputCmd(UINT8* );
    virtual BOOLEAN ProcessInputCmdArgs(UINT8* cmdList_ptr, UINT8 noOfArgs);
}


//One of its member function definition:

BOOLEAN CmdParser_c::ParseInputCmd(UINT8* cmdBuff_ptr)
{
    CmdParser_c *tstObj[MAX_PARSERS]; // <-- creating array of base cls ptr

    RTCcmdParser_c    rtcTstObj;
    UiParser_c        uiP;

    tstObj[0] = &rtcTstObj;          // <-- assigning child1 cls obj
    tstObj[1] = &uiP;                // <-- assigning child2 cls obj 

    if (tstObj[0]->ProcessInputCmd(&inputCmd_ptr[0][0]))
    {
        // do something
    } 
    else if (tstObj[1]->ProcessInputCmd(&inputCmd_ptr[0][0]))
    {
        // do something
    } 
}
```

The code is working. No issues with that. My question is there any flaw in creating array of ptr to a class inside its own member function to achieve runtime polymorphism? Anything wrong with this logic?

Answer (score 0):

I only see one problem: You added specific functionality (`ParseInputCmd`) to the base class which is not used in the derived classes.

Create a derived class `CompositeParser_c : public CmdParser_c { ... }`
and then call the other concrete parsers in the `CompositeParser_c::ProcessInputCmd()` method.